# Errors in compiling gtk program with gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk

I've made a GUI using the glade designer and I've encapsulated the functionality in a class. Here's the class definition that I've written:

```
#ifndef _CLIPSWINDOW_H
#define _CLIPSWINDOW_H 
#include <gtkmm.h>


class ClipsWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    ClipsWindow(BaseObjectType * cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> &refGlade);
    ~ClipsWindow();


protected:
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;
    //MainWindow
    Gtk::Window *main_window;
    // Control buttons.
    Gtk::Button *agenda_btn; // buttons to contain the control buttons in the GUI.
    Gtk::Button *fact_btn;
    Gtk::Button *run_btn;
    Gtk::Button *reset_btn;
    // Menu options.
    //Gtk::MenuButton *options; // Get the options menu
    Gtk::MenuItem *load_item; // Menu items for the "Options menu"
    Gtk::MenuItem *save_item;
    Gtk::MenuItem *change_strategy_item;
    //Gtk::MenuButton *help;
    Gtk::MenuItem *about_item; // Menu item for the "Help Menu"

    // signal handlers for buttons. 
    void on_agendabtn_clicked();
    void on_factbtn_clicked();
    void on_runbtn_clicked();
    void on_resetbtn_clicked();

    // signal handlers for menu items.
    void on_load_activate();
    void on_StrategyOption_activate();
    void on_SaveOption_activate();
    void AboutItem_activate_cb(); 
};







#endif
```

The main function looks like this:

```
Gtk::Main kit(argc,argv);
    //auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "clipsgui.clemson.edu");
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("clipswindow.glade");



    ClipsWindow *cw = 0;
    builder->get_widget_derived("main_window", cw);
    kit.run(*cw);
```

I've taken care to pass the underlying Cobject to the constructor of the `Gtk::Window`. When I try to compile this program using the command `g++ main_app.cpp -o main`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0``, I either get a `.pthread` file or when trying to compile the files individually the error is `gtkmm no such file or directory. However, I've tested gtkmm by creating a small driver program and it compiles just fine. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: [here](https://github.com/ankghost0912/GTKClips) is my github repo of the project. There is a small error when I build `clipswindow.o` but the error still persists.

Comment: As I am unable to reproduce your errors. Incomplete code and it is unknown how you are really compiling your code. Only a guess could be made and at a guess check your options to g++.

Comment: I've added the github repo for my code. Please take a look at it? And how are you compiling the program?